SortOrder mapping problem between Elasticsearch REST High API client and Java Api Client
I am migrating my project from the old Elasticsearch REST High Client to the new Java Api Client.  I use Openapi generator and Mapstruct.
In openapi.yml
    SortOrder:
      enum:
        - ASC
        - DESC
      type: string
      default: DESC

in my mapper interface I have
SortOrder toModel(com....model.SortOrder sortOrder);

If I switch the SortOrder to the new Java Api Client I get this error:

error: The following constants from the source enum have no corresponding constant in the target enum and must be be mapped via adding additional mappings: ASC, DESC.
SortOrder toModel(com....model.SortOrder sortOrder);

When I check the class co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.SortOrder it says:
 Asc("asc"),
 Desc("desc");

but the old one was: org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortOrder
 ASC {
        public String toString() {
            return "asc";
        }

        public int reverseMul() {
            return 1;
        }

        public <T> Comparator<T> wrap(Comparator<T> delegate) {
            return delegate;
        }
    },
    DESC {
        public String toString() {
            return "desc";
        }

        public int reverseMul() {
            return -1;
        }

        public <T> Comparator<T> wrap(Comparator<T> delegate) {
            return delegate.reversed();
        }
    };

I think the problem is that new library uses Asc/Desc instead of ASC/DESC. How can I solve it?

I found the solution.
in my mapper interface:
@ValueMapping(source="ASC", target = "Asc" )
@ValueMapping(source="DESC", target = "Desc" )
SortOrder toModel(com.....model.SortOrder sortOrder);

Since it was in openapi.yml ASC/DESC and library uses Asc/Desc
